# Stop Raspberry Pi automatically assigning additional IP address

Tags: raspbian-buster, dhcp, dhcpcd

I currently have a network of raspberry ip's running Buster connected to a pc on a local network with the wifi interface disabled. The pc is running a DHCP server to assign each of the pi's non-static addresses. However when using the command `hostname -I` while ssh'ed into one of the pi's two addresses appear :

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ hostname -I
169.254.253.76 169.254.0.3
```

Where did this first address (169.254.253.76) come from? And how can I disable/remove the first address (169.254.253.76)?

The second address (169.254.0.3) is the address that was assigned by the DHCP server and is expected.

I cannot / do not want to assign static ip's to the pi's. They must have only one address that is assigned by the DHCP server from the pi's dhcpcd client.

Thanks

-

Comment: the DHCP server should be assigning one of these IP ranges `10.x.x.x` or  `172.16.x.x - 172.31.x.x` or `192.168.x.x`

Comment: The IP range you describe is also called "Zero configuration" a method to get a IP network working without a DHCP server being present.

Answer (score 0):

The Pi is NOT assigning anything (and neither is your DHCP server).
These are [Link-local addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address).

If you "fix" your DHCP server (you have provided no detail) it may assign addresses.

If you are attempting to assign 169. addresses you are doing something drastically wrong because these are not routable.